# Find the user/process details of archive log in Oracle server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

We have a incident at a customer with Oracle archive logs filling up the disk.
We want to find out why this is happening, anyone have any SQLs or scripts to find out which process, user etc that generates so much logs?

Answer (score 0):

"Why it's happening is simple. The app is generating more redo (insert, update, delete) than the current archivelog disk space can handle.  Either they have a rogue process, or they are not performing necessary housekeeping on the archivelogs.

As to the rogue process, the best means of identifying it is probably with logminer.  Logminer if fully documented, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-logminer-utility.html#GUID-3417B738-374C-4EE3-B15C-3A66E01AE2B5).

As for the housekeeping, they *should* be taking regular rman backups of the archivelogs, with the DELETE INPUT option.  At a minimum they should be doing this daily.  For a very active database, it is not out of the question to take that backup more frequently, as needed to stay ahead of the generation.

Also, don't overlook the possibility (probability?) that their archivelog destination is simply too small for their needs.

Also check that if they are using FRA, that they are *really* using FRA.  If their backup destination format specifies the actual name of a directory that happens to be under the FRA, then the FRA mechanism doesn't know anything about that space consumption. And it won't be doing it's own housekeeping.